# Using Azure service bus to send message to Salesforce

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-logic-apps, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-topics

I am working on a POC where I have a publisher which is publishing message to Azure Service Bus using Topics. Multiple subscribers have subscribed to the topic.

One of the subscriber wants to send message to Salesforce. What is the best way to send message to Salesforce

I have following options in mind:

1. Use Azure function to listen to Service bus and then connect with Salesforce to send data. Not sure if a connector already exists.
2. Read data from Service bus using a .net client and then send message to Azure Logic Apps. From Logic app use Salesforce connector to send message to Salesforce. Not sure if Logic apps can directly subscribe to Service bus.

What are pros can cons of both the options ?

Answer (score 0):

Both approaches are valid but the one to chose depends on the level of comfort you have with the aforementioned technologies.

Integration with Salesforce is done via REST API. The LogicApps connector simplifies it quite a bit. Except, I would not read data from Service Bus message using a .NET client and then send message to Azure Logic Apps, but rather trigger Logic Apps with an incoming message using [Service Bus connector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/servicebus/) and invoke Salesforce connector. This way there will be less moving parts.

In case you’re comfortable with [Salesforce REST API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/intro_rest.htm), Function is a valid approach as well.